# Cut a Point cloud image in two Halves- Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst, point-clouds

I have a 3D point cloud image(**.ply format**). I need to **cut it from center dividing into two**. Tried to select only half of the Point cloud  using following code but random points are obtained not the desired ones. Using following logic t divide a point cloud in Half(1/2 of original) and save the resultant in a new point cloud. Neither able to correctly slice cloud image from center nor save it in new cloud.

```
  stepSize = 1;
  indices = 1:stepSize:(i1.Count)/2;
  pt = select(i1, indices);
```

I also checked following code:

```
points3d = i1.Location;
points3d_1 = points3d(points3d(:, 1) < 100, :);
points3d_2 = points3d(points3d(:, 1) >= 100, :);
ptCloud1 = pointCloud(points3d_1);
ptCloud2 = pointCloud(points3d_2);
pcshow(ptCloud1);
figure
pcshow(ptCloud2);
```

Both the snippets are doing same randomly a part is divided and the no matter what range i try in

> point3d(:,1)<**range**

second slice is always full original image. Also the slice image is containing background of original image as shown below. how to get only cloud region stored in new ptCloud1 and ptCloud2.

[image: Expected results]
How can I get new point cloud which is sliced. Using MatalbR2014b

[image]

Comment: There is not enough information here, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. How are you determining where the center of the point cloud is? What is the logic behind the code you tried?

Comment: Detail added. can you please look into it

Comment: This does not answer how you are determining where the center of the point cloud is. Unless your `*.ply` file is made from a left to right scan you're going to get useless data points, which you've seen. Even if it was scanned as such, this would be a terribly non-robust methodology. You need to look at your data in 3D space and determine where the midplane is.

Comment: Manual determination is overhead. I am trying to it done generically. but the logic code i used sliced image from unexpected place( not exactly the center of cloud).

Comment: @BASEERULHASSAN You don't *have* coded logic, you just cut your `*.ply` file in half. Nowhere did I say the process had to be manual, but at some point you have to establish criteria for your midplane.

Comment: Label the axis in your figure using `xlabel('X'); ylabel('Y'); zlabel('Z');`. Then see if you have any points with x > 100 in the first point cloud, or any points with x < 100 in the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to look at the coordinates of the points, and not just their indices.

Let's say `ptCloud` is your `pointCloud` object, and you are using MATLAB R2015b or later with the Computer Vision System Toolbox.

```
>> points3d = ptCloud.Location;
```

gives you the [X,Y,Z] coordinates of your point cloud points in the form or a 3-column matrix. Let's say you want to cut your point cloud in half along the X axis by a plane X = 10. You would do that the following way:

```
points3d_1 = points3d(points3d(:, 1) < 10, :);
points3d_2 = points3d(points3d(:, 1) >= 10, :);
ptCloud1 = pointCloud(points3d_1);
ptCloud2 = pointCloud(points3d_2);
```

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: I beg to differ. Baseer is clearly trying to partition the point cloud spatially. He is using indices, which doesn't work, because the points are not in any particular order. Therefore, he needs to select points based on where they are in space, i.e. based on their coordinates.  My answer points to the correct approach, and suggests better tools, which are a available in a more recent version of MATLAB.

Comment: Dima. Can you pleas look in added detail and let me know how can i access coordinates as  " Accessing point cloud coordinates like a matrix is not possible" hence i am pretty much stuck.

Comment: @BASEERULHASSAN, why is accessing point coordinates like a matrix not possible?  How are the coordinates stored?  Can you put them into a matrix?  Once you do that, you would need to know the equation of the plane that cuts the point cloud. Then you would have to go through the points and select the ones to the left or to the right of the plane.

Comment: "Array formation and parentheses-style indexing with objects of class 'pointCloud' is not allowed."   This is the message i get when i try to access a single point of cloud.

Comment: Ok, now I am confused. Are you using the `pointCloud` object in the Computer Vision System Toolbox? Then use `i1.Location` to get the coordinates. Or use `findPointsInROI` to select the points inside a 3D volume. This is strange, because the documentation says that `pointCloud` was only introduced in R2015a.

Comment: problem didn't solve as per yet. Can you please help with a code example or snippet.

Comment: Good Morning. Just checked into the answer. I have edited the problems. I dn't know why handling point Cloud is so hard in CVST.